# python setup.py install error [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, installation, levenshtein-distance

I try to install python package `python-Levenshtein` using:

> python setup.py install

But I return an error:

> error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\lib'

Then,I use

> pip install python-Levenshtein

but it returns the same error.I try to install other python packages(i.e. `jieba`),it works!I don't know why I can't install `python-Levenshtein`.

My OS is 64-bit,and python3.6 is 32-bit.Is there any influence?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Answer (score 1):

The package is probably relying on some dependency that you don't have installed. I ran into a similar issue with another package and solved using an anaconda environment (it solved the dependencies problems). Maybe you should try to install it using anaconda?

Or try installing the Windows SDK, but it will use some GBs of disk space.

Comment: It doesn't take so much space. In Win10 it is just 16MB

Comment: Thank you! I installed the Windows 8.1 SDK,then I ran the command,the problem can be solved.Although another problem appears:error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory.But anyway this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any problem with the python package python-Levenshtein, it probably should be with the path as the error clearly says, please check if such a path exists. Or go to that path first, copy paste that into the cmd followed by 'cd' (Hope you're already aware of that.) Then try installing it. Just might work if you had made some typing error while entering the path.

Comment: Thank you! I checked the path,and it did not exists.I installed the Windows SDk,the problem has been solved.